# Thunderbird - archived thousands of emails, it now redownloads all of them from the server

Tags: email, thunderbird

I moved a bunch of emails from my local folders inbox to archives, and now whenever I fetch mail, thunderbird redownloads all of those emails back into the inbox.

I have it set to "keep messages on server" as a sort of backup in case something happens to my home computer.

Is it possible to set Thunderbird to only get new messages after X date? Or should I be doing something else.

Comment: So you moved e-mails from your inbox to the archives folder (also located in the remote server?) and now each time you fetch mails you get those moved mails redownloaded back into inbox?

Comment: @nKO: this doesn't work. He's using POP3 email. If he were using IMAP, the archive already would move it on the server side as well.

Comment: Yep, I was just trying to clarify what the flow was, I was suspecting this was a POP3 issue but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @nKo: ah. Yeah, I have much experience in this field as I had to research this for one of our clients. This is definitely POP3. IMAP with archive feature will work correctly, and exchange is not possible without extensions, and even then, the archive would work the same as with IMAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you use POP3 email.

If your hosting also support IMAP email, reconfigure the email and set it as IMAP. If you now archive the email, it will be moved to your archive map on the server as well.

POP3 is never meant to be stored on the server as backup. IMAP can do this though.